# ionic 4/5 app open from browser button click

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I want to open a specific app page (which developed by using ionic 4) from the device browser button click. Can someone help with it?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be useful when asking questions to detail what you have already tried to solve your challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic's InAppBrowser for that.
Here is the link to the plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

If you want to open within the app, you just need to pass the following parameter while opening,

```
  constructor(
   ...
    private iab: InAppBrowser
  ) {}

openInAppBrowser(){
  this.iab.create(`url`, '_self', {
        location: 'no'
      });
}
```

Comment: hi, no actually I want to open my app from the device browser

Comment: ah, then put "system" instead of "_self"

Answer (score 0):

```
try this window.open(url, target, options);
```

ref: Reference to the InAppBrowser window. (InAppBrowser)

url: The URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if the URL contains Unicode characters.

target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
_system: Opens in the system's web browser.
options: Options for the InAppBrowser. Optional, defaulting to: location=yes. (String)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'

constructor(private router: Router, private iab: InAppBrowser) { }
```

openUrl(){

```
this.iab.create('http://google.com', '_self', {
  location:'no'
});
```

}

Comment: No, I want if a website includes a link when the user clicks on it (on a mobile device), I want to open my app through it.